# Why the current equation is different in BJT application?

Tags: current, diodes, bjt

[This](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/%7Ejstiles/412/handouts/7.3%20The%20BJT%20differntial%20pair/section%207_3%20The%20BJT%20Differential%20Pair%20lecture.pdf) is the link I am refereeing for the my study. I am trying to learn how the diode current equation is applied in BJT for differential and common mode analysis. This is the current equation from the document:

[image]

And following is the diode equation:

[image]

By comparing both equations, a subtraction factor of saturation current is missing in the BJT application.
What could be reason for that?

Comment: Because that term is usually so small it doesn't matter. (The results are so close to the same, either way.) The effect of the -1 is to make sure that the current works out to zero when the voltage across the PN junction is zero. (It has a statistical meaning, too. But that's not important right now.)

Comment: Example: Vbe=100mV and Vt=25mV. This makes exp(4)=54.6. Remember: A transistor is operated - at least - around 600mV.

Comment: To clarify what others have said a bit: It's not the fact that it's a BJT that changes anything; it's just that the people writing these equations made different approximations.

Comment: @jonk, your comment is the answer.